# How to make an iPhone web app only available to certain iPhones

Tags: php, iphone

im making an iPhone web app but only certain people need access to it. whats the best way to make it secure without having to get people to login every time they open it.

could i do something like `http://www.domain.com/iphone/index.php?a=1234&b=5678` but make longer strings to make it more secure then on the index.php page get it to check that they all equal the right string?

like: `if($_GET["a"] == '1234' and $_GET["b"] == '5678' { echo 'blah' }` ...etc etc.

or is there a way to check serial numbers or MAC addresses of the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a ip whitelist?
Or make them login once, and save a persistent cookie with a session id.

Comment: could do the IP one but what about when the phones are on 3G... its basically for engineers who do work on customers sites

Comment: @Shehunter2000, Ip adresses will change unless you have a static IP.

Comment: would my way using $_GET function in PHP not be secure enough? obviously i would make the strings alot longer

Comment: Yeah, you could do: First time login goes on the ip, then if it is allowed, it saves the Session UID in a long lasting cookie.

but if the $_GET version is fine for what you are coding, i don't see anything wrong with that! :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a web app available on certain iPhones is to distribute it as `ad-hoc`. You could use Phonegap which is just html/css/js.

-> http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side ssl certificates to authenticate the device on your web server. testflight is doing that, for example.